# Iterating through a function call

Tags: javascript, c++, d3.js, functional-programming

After years of writing loops in C++ the tedious way

```
for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
    ...
}
```

it becomes quite nice to use iterators

```
for(it i=v.begin(); i<v.end(); ++i) {
    ...
}
```

and ultimately moving to range iterators

```
for(auto i:v) {
    ...
}
```

In JavaScript also the `for` can be used, in a style nearly identical
(minus the type declaration and the pre/post increment operator) to
the first one above.

Still, in all of these the `for` is there. The [D3.js](https://d3js.org)
library demonstrates an alternative. One can iterate over an array by writing

```
d3.select("body")
  .selectAll("p")
  .data([4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42])
  .enter().append("p")
  .text(function(d) { return "I’m number " + d + "!"; });
```

Here the `enter` mutates to a `for` loop. The [documentation](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/)
explains nicely the client-side view of joins. What I am missing is a
standalone example of the (functional programming?) style of
converting a function call to an iteration.

No doubt this is not unique to D3.js. This is just where I encountered the idiom.

Can you suggest a few lines of standalone JavaScript code that
demonstrate iteration through a function call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least a couple of built-in functions that come to my mind.

## map()

This one is very obvious.

```
[1, 2, 3]
  .map(someNumber => someNumber * someNumber)
  .map((powered, index) => index + "::" + powered);

  // --> [ "1::1", "2::4", "3::9" ]
```

Chains well, right? Takes some input and produces the result consisting of elements calculated by applying a function element-wise.

*Recommendation:* try to use with pure functions whenever possible (produce the same results for same inputs, don't mutate the original collection if possible, nor produce any side effects).

## forEach()

This function iterates through all elements of an array too, and applies a function, *without* returning anything back. Therefore, it can only *end* a chain of calls, but cannot be used for further chaining.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
  .forEach(number => console.info(number));
```

*Recommendation:* `forEach()` is useful when we want to write some code that will result in a side effect per entry in the collection being iterated.

## filter()

Filter function uses a predicate is used to sift the wheat from the chaff. The predicate is defining a criteria for the items you want to deal with on the next "stage".

```
[null, undefined, 0, 1, 2, 3, NaN, "", "You get the idea"]
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map(filteredElement => filteredElement + "!")

  // --> [ "1!", "2!", "3!", "You get the idea!" ]
```

*Recommendation:* try to use with pure functions whenever possible. I.e. don't do anything else in `filter` other than things immediately related to filtration logic itself.

## Object.keys() and Object.entries()

These two functions are helpful when we need to iterate over object's keys or key-value pairs, rather than an array's elements.

```
const targetObject = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
Object
  .keys(targetObject)
  .map(key => key + "=" + targetObject[key])

  // --> [ "a=1", "b=2", "c=3" ]
```

same result can be achieved like this

```
Object
  .entries({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 })
  .map((key, value) => key + "=" + value)

  // --> [ "a=1", "b=2", "c=3" ]
```

*Recommendation:* you may want to use `Object.hasOwnProperty(...)` when using working with `Object.keys(...)`. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) for details.

## find()

The one is almost trivial. Let's us search for an item that matches a predicate. The search is "left-to-right", and it stops whenever the first "match" is found.

```
[1, 5, 10, 15]
  .find(number >= 7)

  // --> 10
```

**findIndex()** function can be used when we're looking for *a position of an element* that matches a predicate.

## some() and every()

These functions check whether

a) there is at least one element matching a predicate; or
b) each and every element is matching a predicate.

```
const arrayOfNumbers = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];

arrayOfNumbers.every(number => number % 2 === 0); // --> true
arrayOfNumbers.every(number => number % 2 === 1); // --> false

arrayOfNumbers.some(number => number > 1);        // --> true
arrayOfNumbers.some(number => number <= 1);       // --> false
```

## reduce() and `reduceRight()`

The last one to mention in this quick review is the function that takes a list of things and aggregates it into a single result.

```
[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
  .filter(value => value >= 0) // [0, 1, 2, 3]
  .map(value => value + 1)     // [1, 2, 3, 4]
  .reduce((subTotal, currentValue) => subTotal + currentValue, 5);

  // --> 15
```

*Recommendation:* try to use with pure functions whenever possible.

---

Universally applicable note on performance. In my benchmarks (don't have them on hand), a hand-written `for` loop was always faster than `forEach`, `map`, and other iterating functions. I do still prefer the functions unless the performance is being severely affected. There two main reasons for that: 1) easier to avoid off-by-one-errors; 2) the code is more readable, since each single function defines an independent step in the data processing flow, thus making code simpler and more maintainable.

---

I hope, this is an okay overview of some built-in chain-able JavaScript functions. More are [described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype). Take a look at `concat()`, `sort()`, `fill()`, `join()`, `slice()`, `reverse()` -- I frequently use them too.

If you need something like `first()` or `last()`, you will not find them in native functions. Either write your own ones, or use third-party libraries (e.g. [lodash](https://lodash.com/), [rambda.js](http://ramdajs.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example implementation of `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```
function foreach(array, cb) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
        cb(array[i], i, array);
}

foreach([2,8,739,9,0], (n, i) =>
    console.log("number: %s\nindex: %s\n", n, i));
```

### surely I don't have to spoonfeed you do I?

```
function array_iterator(array) {
    var i = 0;

    function next() {
        return array[i++];
    }

    function head() {
        return array[i];
    }

    function tail() {
        return array[array.length-1];
    }

    function more() {
        return i < array.length;
    }

    function done() {
        return !more();
    }

    function reset() {
        i = 0;
    }

    return { next, head, tail, done, more, reset };
}

var nums = [3,34,4];

var iter = array_iterator(nums);

while (iter.more()) {
    console.log(iter.next());
}
```

Comment: That's it? No car/cdr (head/tail)?

Comment: @Sebastian car/cdr approaches only apply to singly-linked list structures. These are indeed common in functional languages, but when all you're interested in is iterating over all elements in (conceptually) an array they're actually pretty inefficient, so you won't find them much outside of Lisp, ML and Haskell. But do read some books on these languages, it's well worth it.